# set environment variable from sh script in systemd service file

Tags: environment-variables, sh, environment, systemd

i try to use ready-made bash script that set env

this is the service that i try to use :

```
[Unit]
Description=myserver service
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/myserver/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh ;/home/ec2-user/venv/bin/python  /home/ec2-user/myserver/myserver.py 2>&1 >> /home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_myserver.log' 
StandardOutput=append:/home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_stdout.log
StandardError=append:/home/ec2-user/myserver/logs/systemd_stderr.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the myserverVars.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export APP1=foo@gmail.com
export APP2_BIND_PASS=xxxxxx
export APP3=xxxxxx
```

the variables in /home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh
are never set, and the server is started without the variables and this is wrong ,
i trying to avoid using Environment key or EnvironmentFile

Answer (score 0):

When you run `/home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh`, it is run in a new process which exits when it finishes, so all the changes to the environment are lost. You need to ask the current shell to execute the script without starting a new process. This is done with the `source` command, which is also available as the "dot" command: `.`. So use

```
/bin/sh -c 'source /home/ec2-user/myserver/config/myserverVars.sh; ...'
```

Comment: it seems that i have a problem that when starting with systemd it don't 
see other profile account variables that used to be in .bash_profile

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only read by bash if it is a login shell, and systemd Units are not logins. You can try replacing `/bin/sh` by `/bin/bash` (as they are not usually the same), then add `source /home/ec2-user/.bash_login;` to the start of the string.

Comment: same problem , looks like starting python script that is a bit  complex then the standard is no trivial in systemd , i will try to pure script in init.d
Thanks for the help